# False dots around circles in pdf export of libreoffice draw

Tags: pdf, draw, libreoffice

When i draw a small circle in LibreOffice draw and export it to pdf i get some extra dots around the circles. Especially in the upper left and lower right outer corner of the circle. 
See example PDF here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/233922/example-dots-circle.pdf
or as a Screenshot here:

[image]

You have any idea how i can get rid of this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see any such dots. Adobe Acrobat 9.5.2 / Windows. What is your viewer reference?

Comment: Adobe Reader 10.1.5 for Windows. I made a snapshot, marked the dots and uploaded it [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/233922/Capture.PNG)

Comment: I see them in your snapshot but still cannot see them here, even not in Adobe Reader X. On the other hand I inspected the PDF page content stream, and indeed, there are operators explicitly drawing those two dots, each of them with minimal size: "0 w 0 J 1 j 374.2 175.3 m 374.2 175.3 l h S" and "0 w 0 J 1 j 396.9 152.6 m 396.9 152.6 l h S" subject to the color "0.50196 0.50196 0.50196 RG". Ah, ok, now I see them here, too... The dots can best be seen when the page is *not* enlarged. Ok, so there indeed are those two dots, and there are explicit commands for drawing them in the PDF

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting the same issue. I'm on openSUSE 12.1 Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [old bug](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37559) and has not been fixed yet. I can reproduce it under Linux and Windows. My version: LibreOffice 4.1.0.

1. Create new file in LO Impress or LO Draw.
2. Draw ellipse (or rounded rectangle, or smile etc.).
3. Set line width e.g. 5mm (for better view).
4. Export as PDF.

I propose two workaround:

1. Export to MS PowerPoint and export in it :/
2. Print to PDF (using e.g. [cups-pdf](http://www.cups-pdf.de/)).

ad 1) You must have MS PP and you graphics may look bad.

ad 2) I use [cups-pdf](http://www.cups-pdf.de/) and PDF look very well, but:

- Text is stored as bitmap graphics (small rectangles)! You can not extract text without using OCR.
- You must use paper format from list (A4, A0, Letter etc.). If you use unstandardised paper format you must use bigger format and you get white bars on PDF. However you can use [pdfcrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/) and remove white bars.
- PDF is always orienter horizontally. If you print as vertically you can rotate pdf using [pdf270](http://freecode.com/projects/pdfjam) command line tool.

Comment: Thanks for the bug list. This is a critical bug as Draw cannot be used professionally to create PDF presentations with this issue.

Comment: Checking in in 2021 with version 6.0.7.3 and this is still an issue!

Comment: I would like to reply to my comment.  I'm now using LibreOffice 7.3.2.2 and it seems to be fixed!

Answer (score 2):

In Adobe Reader (version 11 at least) -> Go to "Preferences" => "Page Display" => uncheck "Enhance thin lines"

Libre Office seems to add dots of 0 size and practically no visibility. When "Enhance thin lines" is checked, Adobe Reader will make these dots visible.

Best wishes,

Patrick

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797782/dzwiedziu-nkg 's answer, I need a multi-step process to fix this issue.

Steps:

1. Open the file in a pdf viewer (Document Viewer for me in Ubuntu.)
2. Print the pdf to a file (also a pdf) from the viewer.  I assume this also uses cups-pdf, as it modifies the image size.  (I don't mind, because I use the next step to eliminate all margins anyways.)
3. Use pdfcrop to remove all the extra space around the actual content's bounding box.  If you just give pdfcrop one argument, it doesn't overwrite the old file, so use the same argument twice:

   ```
   $ pdfcrop monkey.pdf monkey.pdf
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Another "workaround" that worked for me:
Go without outline. You can set the line style in Draw to "none" and just work with flat solid objects.

PS: I see these dots also in Draw, not just in the exported pdf.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is to "patch" the dot in Libreoffice Draw using a white object -- say, a square with white area and white outline. Note that you can not see the dot in Draw. So you first generate the pdf with the orginal drawing, see where the dot appears in the pdf, go back to Draw, and a add a white patch where it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a workaround myself, I've found this [awk script](https://github.com/Sv3n/odg2epsfix) called `odg2epsfix` that will fix the exported EPS to not contain those ghost dots anymore.

I stumbled upon it in this [launchpad bug entry](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openoffice.org/+bug/689349).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in LibreOffice pre-export.

Steps:

1. Right click on the circle in LibreOffice and select "Line"
2. On the "Line" page, set "Corner Style" to "-none-"
3. Save document and Export as PDF.

The dot is gone without removing line enhance. Mine still shows in preview but doesn't print.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is still present in LO 6.0. But if you set "Cap style" to "flat" in the "Line" tab of the "Graphic Styles", the dots disappear from the screen and from the exported pdf.